# CARGAR COMBOBOX - VB.NET & SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net, combobox

soy nuevo en esta plataforma y estoy teniendo un problema. Actualmente estoy migrando proyectos antiguos hechos en VB6 y Access (.mdb). El problema lo tengo a la hora de cargar los combobox. Yo normalmente en VB6 lo hacia de la siguiente manera,

```
Sub CARGAR_CARGOS()
Do While Not RGCARGOS.EOF
    cbocargo.AddItem RGCARGOS!id & " - " & RGCARGOS!DESCRIPCION
    RGCARGOS.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

De esta manera cuando tenia que guardar el dato del combo solo guardaba el ID con el MID como una forma de normalizar la tabla y no crear redundancias.
Alguien me podrá orientar como hacer lo mismo o que en el formulario me muestre la descripcion y cuando el usuario le de guardar almacene el ID o el Index que tiene en la BD.

Desde ya muchas gracias a todos los que se toman un segundo para responderme

End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalmente en VB.NET se suele usar MVVM (Model-View-ViewModel), para separar la vista de la lógica. Digo esto, porque lo ideal es crear una lista en el ViewModel, rellenar los datos en esa lista, y luego simplemente vincular la lista al combo.

Sería algo así en el ViewModel (o en el Code-behind):

```
Dim MiLista as List(Of Regargo) = New List(Of Recargo)
MiLista = servicio.CargarRegargos() ' o como sea que lees los regargos de la BBDD (entiendo que es lo que llamas RGCARGOS)
```

Y luego en la vista, en el XAML, lo que pondrías sería:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MiLista}"/>
```

Eso que pongo es lo básico, luego tendrías que jugar con `DisplayMemberPath`, `SelectedValuePath`, `SelectedValue`, etc. para afinar el comportamiento del ComboBox.

En el caso de no usar XAML (porque trabajes con Windows Forms, por ejemplo), sería usar la propiedad `ItemsSource` directamente en el código:

```
cbocargo.ItemsSource = MiLista
```

Al principio cuesta un poco cambiar la mentalidad de VB6 a VB.NET, pero en seguida te acostumbras, porque es mucho más cómodo manejar una lista en el código que un elemento ComboBox, que en realidad pertenece a la vista.